# largest palindrome product in java

Tags: java

I have written a code for the fourth question of Euler Project.

The question is:
A palindromic number reads the same both ways. The largest palindrome made from the product of two 2-digit numbers is 9009 = 91 × 99.

Find the largest palindrome made from the product of two 3-digit numbers.

Here is my code:

```
public class LargestPalindromeProduct {
private static int product;//integer palindrome number
private static String palindrome;//string palindrome

private static int largestPalindrome(){
    for(int i = 100; i<=999; i++){
        for(int k = 100; k<=999; k++){
            product = i*k;

            palindrome  = Integer.toString(product);

            for(int j = 0; j<= palindrome.length()-1; j++){
                if(palindrome.charAt(j) == palindrome.length() - 1 - j){
                    return product;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return product;
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int largestPalindrome = largestPalindrome();
    System.out.println(largestPalindrome);
}
```

}

This code gives 998001 as the output.
Can you help me to find where the problem is?

Comment: `j<= palindrome.length()-1` is strange. just use `j < palindrome.length()`.

Comment: (by the way, the same inefficiency applies to your palindrome check -- you check every character twice)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Close, but for your pattern to work, you must try all combinations and return the largest one.  Also, don't short circuit the method on a mis-match, just break out of the loop.

Try a couple changes similar to what i've added...

```
public class LargestPalindromeProduct {

private static int largestPalindrome() {
    int max = 0;
    for(int i = 100; i<=999; i++) {
            for(int k = 100; k<=999; k++) {
                int product = i*k;
                if (product <= max) {
                    continue;
                }
                String palindrome  = Integer.toString(product);
                boolean good = true;
                for(int j = 0; j<= palindrome.length()-1; j++) {
                    if(palindrome.charAt(j) != palindrome.charAt(palindrome.length() - 1 - j)) {
                        good = false;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (good)
                    max = product;
            }
        }
    }
    return max;
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int largestPalindrome = largestPalindrome();
    System.out.println(largestPalindrome);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are returning the moment you get 1 match instead of continuing checking until ALL match.

```
 if(palindrome.charAt(j) == palindrome.length() - 1 - j){
     return product;
 }
```

As @soong has pointed out the actual comparison is doing `charAt()` vs `length`

Better check how you are doing your comparisons.

Comment: Yes  `3453` will provide a match on the `3` but doesn't mean the value is a palindrome... Anywhere he gets a partial match it will be returning

Comment: It's this AND the fact that `palindrome.length() - 1 - j` needs to be `palindrome.charAt(palindrome.length() - 1 - j)` (as is, it's comparing the first character to a number derived from the length of the string)

Comment: also, as soon as you really find *one* palindrome, you're aborting. That surely won't find the *biggest* palindrome.

Comment: For more speed, try to reverse the loop. If you start from 999, you will probably find the answer faster. And with some cleverness, maybe the first palindrome you will find will be the biggest.

Comment: *add more cleverness* is almost always a good approach. Cheers, @JFPicard!

Answer (score 0):

What I did was start at 999999 and count downward, then test if the number was a palindrome, and if the number was a palindrome, test if it had 2 integer factors.

I'm not going to give you all the code, but here's one way to check for a palindrome that you might not have thought of.

```
public static boolean isPalindrome(int palindrome) {
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(Integer.toString(palindrome));
    builder.reverse();
    return Integer.valueOf(builder.toString()) == palindrome;
}
```